# Pandas merge handling duplicates in join output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, merge

Is there a nice way to bring only one row, preferably random in one-to-many matching during left join in Pandas?

e.g

```
left = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2],[3,3,3], [9,9,9], [1,3,2]]
right = [[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[3,2,2], [3,2,9], [3,2,2]]
left = np.asarray(left)
right = np.asarray(right)
left = pd.DataFrame(left)
right = pd.DataFrame(right)
joined_left = left.merge(right, how="left", left_on=[0], right_on=[0])
```

So this is what we get

```
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  9  9  9
4  1  3  2

   0  1  2
0  1  2  2
1  1  2  3
2  3  2  2
3  3  2  9
4  3  2  2

   0  1_x  2_x  1_y  2_y
0  1    1    1  2.0  2.0
1  1    1    1  2.0  3.0
2  2    2    2  NaN  NaN
3  3    3    3  2.0  2.0
4  3    3    3  2.0  9.0
5  3    3    3  2.0  2.0
6  9    9    9  NaN  NaN
7  1    3    2  2.0  2.0
8  1    3    2  2.0  3.0
```

So now I want to have output to be of the same size as my left dataframe and when there are more than one match in right dataframe I want to bring only single random column.

Is there a nice way of doing it using pandas short cut tricks?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shuffle `right` and `drop_duplicates(...[, keep='first'])` before merging.

```
right2 = right.sample(frac=1).drop_duplicates(subset=[0])
left.merge(right2, how='left', left_on=[0], right_on=[0])

   0  1_x  2_x  1_y  2_y
0  1    1    1  2.0  2.0
1  2    2    2  NaN  NaN
2  3    3    3  2.0  2.0
3  9    9    9  NaN  NaN
4  1    3    2  2.0  2.0
```

We shuffle `right` first, and then drop every duplicate except the first row (considering only column #0), which is the same as randomly selecting a row.

Comment: I see, so you drop duplicates for a merge key column right. Ingenious! Thank you

Comment: @YohanRoth - in this case - if your first row of the output is `1 1 1 2.0 2.0`, I think that guarantees the last row is also `1 3 2 2.0 2.0` since you've dropped `1 2 3`.  From your question asking for a `random` choice, I'm a bit concerned that this may not be the behavior you want.  Perhaps it's fine, but worth making sure it's consistent with what you want.